# ViewBox vs Grid

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

Whats the difference between these two, and which is the better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are completely different control!

A Grid allows you to arrange its multiple children according to a a pre-defined set of rows / columns.

A ViewBox scales its single child to fill a certain area on the screen.